# Screen temporarily turning black when switching workspaces and applications

Tags: 18.04, graphics, display, workspaces

- Version: Ubuntu 18.04
- GNOME: 3.28.2
- Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4

Screen temporarily turns black (not off, because there's still a glow), lasting anywhere between 1 and 20 seconds. When it happens once and is of the briefer variety (1-3 seconds), it happens again a few times in rapid succession. Sometimes the black screen begins with the bottom third of the screen being briefly sheered diagonally. It seems to be triggered by things like switching workspaces (e..g. ctr+alt+down) and switching applications. If I do nothing, it doesn't happen.

I've tried

- rebooting (a few times)
- restarting display manager `sudo systemctl restart display-manager`
- searching Google
- crying

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was an issue with the drivers. A reinstall of Ubuntu (overkill, perhaps, but I think it was not a bad idea for other reasons too) seems to have fixed the problem.